# Why can we write $B=UAU^{-1}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This question is from the 1979 Berkeley Problems in Mathematics. It asked me to prove that every complex matrix $A$ can be written in the form $$B=UAU^{-1}$$ with $U$ unitary and $B$ upper triangular. The Jordan decomposition only gives me that $U$ invertible, which is not enough in this case. I do not know a simple trick to turn invertible matrices into unitary matrices (like the one that works for the real case $C=\sqrt{DD^{T}}$).

Comment: fixed the typos.

Comment: Look up the Schur decomposition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just so this question does not remain unanswered:

As I've already mentioned, the decomposition you are interested in is in fact the (somewhat) famous **Schur decomposition**; that is, any matrix is unitarily similar to a triangular matrix. (In the special case of normal matrices, the triangular matrix is diagonal, and your Schur decomposition is now the *spectral decomposition*). For proofs of the existence of this very useful decomposition, see [this](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=xi5omWiQ-3kC&pg=PA337), [this](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=mlOa7wPX6OYC&pg=313), or [this](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=FtC9rHW7ORMC&pg=PA11).